# How do I change the UV Mapping algorithm, for example LSCM to Angle Based?

Tags: uv

Is there a GUI option to change the algorithm ? I want to compare all the options Angle Based, LSCM etc. I'm using UV mapping to correct image distortion.
I'm not even sure what the default algorithm is and were I can check which one is using.
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @JachymMichal for the info. I was looking for the pop-up menu but could not find it anywhere. For any noob linux users like me (not sure if it's the same for windows and mac) this pop-up menu somehow emerges from the bottom and only appears after you unwrap (I think). You can change the algo from ABF to LSCM after that and reunwrap. Once again thanks Jachym!

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between Angle Based (ABF) and Conformal (LSCM) algorithm.
It's in the pop-up menu after you unwrap.

<sub>And if you want to dig deeper, [here is a Blender DevSource page](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Dev:Source/Textures/UV/Unwrapping/) explaining both algorithms.</sub>

[image]